# organize pictures into destination folders automatically based on date

Tags: photos.app, aperture

I have a ~50000 pictures:

- located in multiple folders
- not organized,
- there are duplicates
- source contains videos, but I need only pictures

I would like to organize all of them into subfolders automatically as:

targetdirectory/YEAR/MONTH/DAY/*.jpg

either original filename or renamed something like YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.ext would be ok..

Should merge from multiple sources and should skip duplicates...

I tried iphoto and aperture but it wasn't working 100%

Thank you !

Comment: Do you want targetdirectory to be in your home directory?  How comfortable are you with the command line vs. a GUI solution? I'm working on writing up a little program that could solve your problem.

Comment: Daniel,
command line is fine..
I just cant believe this trivial not in some bigger apps..
I am also thinking to do a command line php script to organize them...
Thank you

Comment: @andraskende Is the date currently part of the filename or are you wanting this based on current date of the file?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Hazel (http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php) to organise and file your photos.

In Hazel you can create rules to act on files, these rules can be based on for example file metadata or EXIF information.
The rule actions can create new folders and subfolders from these attributes and copy the files into the right location (it can also handle file name conflicts).

I found an example to set this one up on [dpreview](http://forums.dpreview.com/forums/read.asp?forum=1017&message=27106767). (In step 4.c you specify that it should only work with pictures, it will ignore the videos).

The only thing you might need to do is to copy the files from the current folders into the folder where the Hazel rule will trigger.

Answer (score 1):

I have a perl script which does something similar, my target directory is targetdirectory/YEAR/YEAR-MONTH-DAY, but this can easily be changed in your copy of the script: https://github.com/brablc/clit/blob/master/iphoto-copy-export-to-archive-dir

If you have multiple directories you could run it as:

`find . -name '*.jpg' | iphoto-copy-export-to-archive-dir targetdirectory`

It would skip duplicates if they have same file name and same size.